# Graph request to list root children returns empty

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the [graph explorer](https://graphexplorer2.azurewebsites.net) to try list the root's children via call to `GET /drive/root/children` but getting empty response (while I have many files & folders in my directory):

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drive/root/children",
  "value": []
}
```

Any idea why and how to fix this?

Comment: If you request `/drive/root?$select=webUrl` you can see the URL at which the API is looking for folders and documents. Could you confirm that you have files and documents in that location?

Comment: What permissions is the app asking for? Can you decode the auth token using http://jwt.calebb.net/ and let us know the values on the scp claim?

Comment: @WaldekMastykarz-MVP here's the response to `/drive/root?$select=webUrl`:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drive/root(webUrl)/$entity",
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
  "@odata.id": "drive/root",
  "id": "01AAZ7JP56Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ",
  "webUrl": "https://skyformationenterprise.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents"
}
```

Comment: @Yina the graph explorer. it asks for (and I gave it):

Create, read, update and delete your tasks and projects (preview),
View OneNote notebooks that you can access (preview),
Read items in all site collections,
Read selected files,
Read your files and files shared with you,
Read your contacts,
Read your calendars,    
Read your mail,
Read directory data,
Read all groups,
Read all users' full profiles,
Read all users' basic profiles,
Sign you in and read your profile,
View your OneNote notebooks (preview),    
Read your relevant people list (preview),
Sign you in and read your profile

Comment: @Nadav could you confirm that you have files/folders @ https://skyformationenterprise.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents?

Comment: @WaldekMastykarz-MVP indeed, empty. but why is this api looking for files in this folder and not my root directory ?. edit: never mind. Marek pointed out the API difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use GET /me/drive/root/children to list your personal drive. GET /drive/root/children lists the content of your organization's drive/SharePoint site.